# ROS2 colcon build fails - can't copy: doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: ros

I have a ROS2 package which is failing to build. I'm following the ROS2 "Setting Up a Robot Simulation (Webots)" [tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Simulators/Webots/Setting-up-a-Robot-Simulation-Webots.html), and when I got to [section 6](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Simulators/Webots/Setting-up-a-Robot-Simulation-Webots.html#modify-the-setup-py-file) "Modify the setup.py file", I changed my file like so:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from glob import glob

package_name = 'ad_boxtra'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        ('share/' + package_name, glob('launch/*.py')), # include all launch files
        ('share/' + package_name, glob('resource/*.urdf')), # include all webots-related resource files
        ('share/' + package_name + '/webots_simulation/worlds',    # include desired webots worlds
            ['worlds/adboxtra_2022_simplified.wbt']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='redacted',
    maintainer_email='redacted',
    description="redacted",
    license='MIT License',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_robot_driver = ad_boxtra.my_robot_driver:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

I then ran `colcon build` with debug info from the root of my workspace and got:

```
user@host:~/my_ws $ colcon build --packages-select ad_boxtra --event-handlers console_direct+
Starting >>> ad_boxtra
running egg_info                        
writing ../../build/ad_boxtra/ad_boxtra.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to ../../build/ad_boxtra/ad_boxtra.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to ../../build/ad_boxtra/ad_boxtra.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing requirements to ../../build/ad_boxtra/ad_boxtra.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to ../../build/ad_boxtra/ad_boxtra.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file '../../build/ad_boxtra/ad_boxtra.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file '../../build/ad_boxtra/ad_boxtra.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build
running build_py
running install
running install_lib
running install_data
error: can't copy 'adboxtra_2022_simplified.wbt': doesn't exist or not a regular file
--- stderr: ad_boxtra
error: can't copy 'adboxtra_2022_simplified.wbt': doesn't exist or not a regular file
---
Failed   <<< ad_boxtra [0.63s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.70s]
  1 package failed: ad_boxtra
  1 package had stderr output: ad_boxtra
---
Failed   <<< ad_boxtra [0.62s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.71s]
  1 package failed: ad_boxtra
  1 package had stderr output: ad_boxtra
```

**Why is this colcon build failing?** If it helps, here's my directory tree:

```
AdBoxtra
├── ad_boxtra
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_robot_driver.py
├── launch
│   └── my_robot_webots.launch.py
├── LICENSE
├── package.xml
├── README.md
├── resource
│   ├── ad_boxtra
│   └── my_robot.urdf
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── test
│   ├── test_copyright.py
│   ├── test_flake8.py
│   └── test_pep257.py
├── urdf
└── webots_simulation
    ├── controllers
    │   └── arm_sweep
    │       └── arm_sweep.py
    ├── libraries
    ├── plugins
    │   ├── physics
    │   ├── remote_controls
    │   └── robot_windows
    ├── protos
    └── worlds
        └── adboxtra_2022_simplified.wbt

27 directories, 63 files
```

I did observe that in the `install/` directory of my workspace, it seems that `share/ad_boxtra/webots_simulation/worlds/` exists, but there's no `.wbt` files inside it. I don't know why this is though:

```
$ tree ~/rover_ws/install/ad_boxtra/
/home/redacted/rover_ws/install/ad_boxtra/
├── lib
│   ├── ad_boxtra
│   │   ├── conversationalist
│   │   ├── drive_control_serial
│   │   └── turtle_ad_boxtra
│   └── python3.8
│       └── site-packages
│           ├── ad_boxtra
│           │   ├── conversationalist.py
│           │   ├── drive_control_serial.py
│           │   ├── __init__.py
│           │   ├── my_robot_driver.py
│           │   ├── __pycache__
│           │   │   ├── conversationalist.cpython-38.pyc
│           │   │   ├── drive_control_serial.cpython-38.pyc
│           │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│           │   │   ├── my_robot_driver.cpython-38.pyc
│           │   │   └── turtle_ad_boxtra.cpython-38.pyc
│           │   └── turtle_ad_boxtra.py
│           └── ad_boxtra-0.0.0-py3.8.egg-info
│               ├── dependency_links.txt
│               ├── entry_points.txt
│               ├── PKG-INFO
│               ├── requires.txt
│               ├── SOURCES.txt
│               ├── top_level.txt
│               └── zip-safe
└── share
    ├── ad_boxtra
    │   ├── drive_control.launch.py
    │   ├── hook
    │   │   ├── ament_prefix_path.dsv
    │   │   ├── ament_prefix_path.ps1
    │   │   ├── ament_prefix_path.sh
    │   │   ├── pythonpath.dsv
    │   │   ├── pythonpath.ps1
    │   │   └── pythonpath.sh
    │   ├── my_robot.urdf
    │   ├── my_robot_webots.launch.py
    │   ├── package.bash
    │   ├── package.dsv
    │   ├── package.ps1
    │   ├── package.sh
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   ├── package.zsh
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── drive_control.launch.cpython-38.pyc
    │   └── webots_simulation
    │       └── worlds
    ├── ament_index
    │   └── resource_index
    │       └── packages
    │           └── ad_boxtra
    └── colcon-core
        └── packages
            └── ad_boxtra

18 directories, 38 files
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html):

> data_files specifies a sequence of (directory, files) pairs in the following way...

You wrote
`('share/' + package_name + '/webots_simulation/worlds',['worlds/adboxtra_2022_simplified.wbt'])`, but it should be `('share/' + package_name + '/webots_simulation/worlds',['adboxtra_2022_simplified.wbt'])`.

Comment: This suggestion didn't fix the issue: `error: can't copy 'adboxtra_2022_simplified.wbt': doesn't exist or not a regular file`

Comment: Please see my post edit, I've added more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `build` folder too. Just delete `build` and `install` and try again. It could be that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).